# Several Objective-C objects become Invalid for no reason, sometimes

Tags: objective-c, iphone

```
- (void)loadLocations {
    NSString *url = @"<URL to a text file>";
    NSStringEncoding enc = NSUTF8StringEncoding; 
    NSString *locationString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] usedEncoding:&enc error:nil];
    NSArray *lines = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    for (int i=0; i<[lines count]; i++) {
        NSString *line = [lines objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *components = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
        Restaurant *res = [byID objectForKey:[components objectAtIndex:0]];

        if (res) {
            NSString *resAddress = [components objectAtIndex:3];
            NSArray *loc = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[components objectAtIndex:1], [components objectAtIndex:2]];
            [res.locationCoords setObject:loc forKey:resAddress];   
        }
        else {
            NSLog([[components objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@" res id not found."]);
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few weird things happening here. First, at the two lines where the NSArray lines is used, this message is printed to the console-

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFDictionary count]: method sent to an uninitialized mutable dictionary object'
```

which is strange since lines is definitely not an NSMutableDictionary, definitely is initialized, and because the app doesn't crash.

Also, at random points in the loop, all of the variables that the debugger can see will become Invalid. Local variables, property variables, everything. Then after a couple lines they will go back to their original values. setObject:forKey never has an effect on res.locationCoords, which is an NSMutableDictionary. I'm sure that res, res.locationCoords, and byId are initialized.

I also tried adding a retain or copy to lines, same thing. I'm sure there's a basic memory management principle I'm missing here but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Doesn't fix the root cause, but you can loop through the array with fast enumeration `for (NSString* line in lines) { ... }`.

Comment: I had that, and changed it to see if it had something to do with the problem.

Comment: All I've got to throw in is that any time I say "I'm sure," I probably shouldn't have been.

Comment: Everything works fine besides that function, and all the other objects are heavily used.

Comment: Eh for what it's worth, the problem fixed itself after a couple days, I changed literally nothing *shrug*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `-[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` call must end with a `nil` (because a C function needs it to determine how many arguments you gave it).

Comment: Good catch. Apparently I added that at some point and that may have had something to do with why it started working, all I can remember is that the problem disappeared.

Comment: I'm actually going to mark you as the answer, because that looks like the only thing that I've changed since it was broken, so if the problem wasn't outside of that function, I feel like it had to be that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with memory management here. Maybe add some error checking:

- check the error: parameter of initWithContentsOfURL:
- check locationString != nil
- check lines != nil